# How to force a web service to run just once

Tags: service, web

I've written a web service which outputs some (sensitive) data to strongly authenticated clients.

I've been asked to let any single request to work only once, to avoid any security risk :-(

I'm asking myself:

- does this requirement makes any sense to you?
- if it does, how would you accomplish this? I would like - if possible - to avoid to have to keep a requests archive...
- if it can be of any use, the language choosen for the application on server is perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to more information about the service to determine if it makes sense or not. However I don't think is possible to prevent duplicate requests without keeping some kind of log. Maybe you could SHA hash the request and store that in a table to compare future request hashes?

Comment: The service provides a PDF document with medical data. Do you mean you'd add - for example - a random key parameter to the request, and then would log the sha1 digest of each request? I was just thinking about a similar solution...

Comment: Oh, so you have to deal with HIPAA? Yikes. What would happen if the client wanted to legitimately re-request the service?

Comment: :-) No I deal with italian SSN (that's worse, probably...). Yes, that's why I added 'random': random keys are hopefully univocal...